# Determining pixels, percentages, and element size in css styles

Tags: html, css

This is a general question for you web-dev folks out there. I've seen lots of CSS out there that has a very specific pixel or percentage count for css elements like "padding" and "height", etc. Experienced web developers seem to really nail the positioning of their content. I find for doing something as simple as centring a  element into the flat middle of my screen, it takes me lots of testing with different px or % values for "padding-left" or "height" in my styles before I get it right, and it just feels clumsy.

So I was wondering, is there some rule of thumb, or guideline, that you all follow for choosing px or % values when building your web pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using percentages corresponds to fluid designs, the web page thus created will be responsive in nature. Using pixels is as if you are using fixed values, the web page won't be responsive. this design pattern will be suitable to web pages which are intended to be kept at a fixed size. For responsive design it's good to use bootstrap, as they have done most of the handling of css for you (indeed for different screen sizes and resolutions), we just need to use the appropriate css classes as per our need. Doing so, the web page will be responsive.

It's recommended to use responsive design, go for % values so that the web page doesn't break for different screen sizes and resolutions.

Comment: aight cheers man, thanks